# Find $\prod^\infty_{n=1} (1 - 10^{-3* 2^n})$.

Tags: infinite-product

Find the infinite product:
$0.999 \times 0.999999 \times 0.999999999999 \cdots$, where the number of $9$s in each term is double that of the previous term.

I am thinking of considering the analogous problem $0.9 \times 0.99 \times 0.999 \cdots$, but this alone seems quite hard to solve. To solve this analogous problem, I was thinking of considering the numbers that have a binary sum of digits of $1$, $2$, etc., but this does not give anything nice.

On the other hand, is there a nice way to express

$\frac{0.999 \times 0.999999 \times 0.999999999999 \cdots}{0.9 \times 0.99 \times 0.999 \cdots}$?

Comment: Is my edit fine with you ?

Answer (score 15):

We can generalise this problem as follows:
$$s = \prod_{n =0}^{\infty}(1-x^{2^n}) = (1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^4)(1-x^8) ...$$
where $x=0.001$ in your specific problem.

If we expand this product as
$$s=1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_mx^m$$
then each $a_m$ is either 1 or -1 because there is only one way to express each m as the sum of powers of two (binary expansion). And we can go further and see that $a_m=(-1)^{t_m}$ where $t_m$ is the number of 1s in the binary expansion of m ($t_m$ is related to the [Thue-Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence)). If we say that $t_0=0$ then we have
$$s=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{t_m}x^m=1-x-x^2+x^3-x^4+x^5+x^6-x^7-x^8 ...$$
I don't know of a simpler way of expressing this limit.

Comment: thanks! On the other hand, is there a nice way to express

0.999×0.999999×0.999999999999⋯0.9×0.99×0.999⋯0.999×0.999999×0.999999999999⋯0.9×0.99×0.999⋯?

Comment: Good idea, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are looking for $$P_k=\prod _{n=0}^k \left(1-10^{-3\times 2^{n}}\right)$$ I must confess that I do not see any possible closed form but we can notice very interesting patterns as shown below 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & P_k \\
 0 & 0.99900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.99899900100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
 2 & 0.99899900099900100099900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
 3 & 0.99899900099900100099899900100099900099899900100000000000000000000 \\
 4 & 0.99899900099900100099899900100099900099899900099900100099900099900 \\
 5 & 0.99899900099900100099899900100099900099899900099900100099900099900 \\
 6 & 0.99899900099900100099899900100099900099899900099900100099900099900 \\
 7 & 0.99899900099900100099899900100099900099899900099900100099900099900 \\
 8 & 0.99899900099900100099899900100099900099899900099900100099900099900 \\
 9 & 0.99899900099900100099899900100099900099899900099900100099900099900 \\
 10 & 0.99899900099900100099899900100099900099899900099900100099900099900
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: thanks! On the other hand, is there a nice way to express

0.999×0.999999×0.999999999999⋯0.9×0.99×0.999⋯0.999×0.999999×0.999999999999⋯0.9×0.99×0.999⋯?

Comment: @TheMathTroll. My way is not nice at all ! gandalf61's answer is nice.